# I need to Parse whole java code and save statements in a tree structure for making Control flow graph

Tags: java, parsing

I need to identify java source code all type of statements and store them in a tree structure to make a control flow graph! what i cannot understand is how should i read a java source code so that my program may distinguish all different types of statements in java( if,for, classes, methods etc.)
Do i need to add the whole grammar of java language?

what i cannot understand is how should i read a java source code so that my program may distinguish all different types of statements in java( if,for, classes, methods etc.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Read java source code (uncompiled)
   `file extension is .java` and it's just a regular text so this should be a trivial task.
2. Now depends what you wanted to parse and to store.
   The best way is to have all the grammar and check the file.

There are tools that are doing *lexical analysis*, also known as *language recognition*, and also generate for you [AST (abstract syntax tree)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). 
Eg. [JavaCC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaCC) or [ANTLR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR).

But maybe you want just a custom parse(partial).
So you can store the keywords in a data-structure (`if, for`) and parse the file accordingly.
(and with some patterns for instruction eg:`if`. More could made simple automates_`DFA` for each instruction or maybe `regular expression`)

Even here is a little bit work.
 Eg. Want `if` from instruction not `if` from a text. `String s="if"`. 
Or/And are you sure that every time will parse a valid java file? )

Comment: Thank you so much.... your answer helped a lot

Comment: Glad to be useful. Good Luck further !